# What is the number next to my name in chat?

Tags: support, chat

I was in P.SE chat recently, and after posting two rather long posts, a "4471" appeared under my name.  There was no number under anyone else's name.  I thought it might be my chat rep, but I don't have rep *near* that high on any site.  The tooltip just says "4471"(Wow, that's helpful).  What is this mystery number?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As the Programmers chat is on chat.SE, the number below your gravatar is your total reputation, across all Stack Exchange sites (no matter how little reputation you may have on them). Adding up the values shown on your [associated accounts tab](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/152101/john?tab=accounts) will currently give you 4471.

I'd agree that the tooltip could be a bit more descriptive though. Currently it's just used to show you the real value in cases where the reputation was rounded for display purposes. Prepending "reputation score" to the front of the number like is done in many places on the main site would probably work.

Comment: Ah that makes sense.  To think, a simple tooltip could have prevented this whole question.

Comment: @John Yeah, heh. I'll mention it to a chat dev or two if they don't come across this question, and see what they think about improving it.

Comment: we've seen it.

Answer (score 6):

To answer the other half of your question: the reason there were no numbers under anyone else's names was because they didn't post 'rather long posts'. You will observe that if there is enough vertical space, the gravatar moves below the user name, and if there is further space, the reputation is shown beneath that.

Comment: Very enlightening.  Thank you for your time.  +1.